# Execute another exe when uninstall finished in Windows Installer

Tags: windows-installer

In my application I have copied some files in temp folder. But when I uninstall my application I need to remove these files also. with this I need to uninstall some third party dll's 
To acomplish this I have created one program but how to call it when uninstall finished. 
i have added Uninstall link in User Menu folder of windows installer and pass product code as argument .
I have added that program exe to custom action under Uninstall folder but its not executing at all.
How to do this please explain.
I dont want to use any third part tool to do this.

Comment: to get a helpful answer it would really be useful to let us know what tool are you using to build the installer. Wix, VS, Orca, etc....

Comment: Oh so sorry. I found answer. I am doing it with orca. When I started to do I even dont know orca so I have not mentioned.

Comment: http://www.itninja.com/question/how-to-call-exe-in-orca-during-uninstall-only answer